# Encode to base64 with Php gives different result than with Python 3

Tags: php, python-3.x, base64

I am trying to convert a code in Php to Python, it consists of encoding a variable obtained with the *chr* function with base64 using the *base64_encode* function.

Here is the code in Php:

```
$data = chr(ord('a')+ord('b'));
$data = base64_encode($data);
echo $data;
```

result:

```
ww==
```

Here is what I tried to do in Python:

```
from base64 import b64encode

data = chr(ord('a')+ord('b'))
data = b64encode(data.encode()) // data.encode() is mandatory or I get an error saying that b64encode require a bytes-like object
print(data)
```

result:

```
b'w4M='
```

Thank you for your help

Aymeric

Comment: pls provide the whole python code 'cause getting UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) for base64.b64encode

Comment: @myxaxa done :)

Comment: and which python version do you have? :)

Comment: Python 3.6.0, I just removed the "self" in my code it was from a class, but dont need here

Comment: so I've tested it - and it's works fine for me, but I removed .encode for python script. i'm sure it's because of it

Comment: testing on old version - Python 2.7.15rc1

Comment: For me, when I do **data = chr(ord('a')+ord('b'))** then **data = b64encode(data)** I get an error: *TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'*

Comment: yeap, cause you using 3.6.0 :)

Comment: @myxaxa but I need to use Python 3 ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the real answer to the question, but the problem is that python string from version 3 are in unicode. so the php-code can be replaced:

```
<?php
$data = chr(ord('a')+ord('b'));
$data = utf8_encode($data);

echo base64_encode($data); //w4M=
```

or you can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-chr.php for this

so for changing python code to work it as php - you need to encode data in latin-1:

```
from base64 import b64encode

data = chr(ord('a')+ord('b')).encode('latin-1')
data = b64encode(data)

print(data) # b'ww=='
print(data.decode()) # ww==
```